# Moving filtered data into variant variable array

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, array

I am currently trying to automate a manual task. I have filtered my data and this works fine if I copy and paste the visible range into another sheet. I am trying to write the visible data into a variant variable array. I want to hold this in memory and than write this to a range. Every time I do this I get #NAs. Your thoughts and advice appreciated.

```
Sub Derivatives()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lRow1 As Long
    Dim Fields() As Variant
    Dim wb1 As Workbook

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

    lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With ws
        Range("$G$9:$I$22479").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="TRUE"
        lRow1 = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Fields = ws.Range("G9").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        Range("K9").CurrentRegion = Fields
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You would need to iterate the areas, then the rows in each area adding each cell individually.  Or Iterate all the rows and add if visible.  It may be quicker to copy and paste the visible then load the new range into the array.

Comment: Hi Scot I am keen to load this into variant array, to hold it as memory, and it is also learning element. I am slightly puzzled how this can be done

Comment: As my last comment stated, you can't do it in mass. I gave you three options on how to do it.

Comment: @user3287522, think you are trying to copy filtered data at `G9' ! but your source data overlapping it since the Range to filter is G9:I22479 ??

Comment: @user3287522, one more issue I've found is Criteria ,, the way you are using is wrong even you can't use it as `"True"`. Better store TRUE in cell and modify command line as, `Criteria1:=Range("E3").Value`

Comment: Rajesh so I had a huge list of items 25000 rows and I created a vlookup list only items on vlookup range would come up as true, which I would filter. I believe there must be a way of passing into array the filtered items